# Mozilla Thunderbird: recovering emails from global-messages-db.sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recovery, thunderbird, mbox

How can I recover lost emails from Thunderbird's *global-messages-db.sqlite*?

My PC kernel panicked in the middle of migrating some emails from Imap to local storage. As a result, that migration did not complete writing to disk.

Due to the failed migration, many emails exist in *global-messages-db.sqlite* but do not exist in corresponding mbox files (eg not in  *Mail/username@hostname.tld*). I verified that the emails exist in *global-messages-db.sqlite* via [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). In fact, I've successfully manually extracted the content of some critical messages.

Upon startup, Thunderbird is culling from *global-messages-db.sqlite* emails it does not find in mbox files. If I replace the active *global-messages-db.sqlite* with a version containing my lost emails, Thunderbird ignores and eventually removes those lost emails.

This would be a trivial dilemma if I still had access to the Imap account. Unfortunately, I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting a converter is trivial

I would quickly code a gloda->mbox converter, that's probably your fastest path to success. You've already discovered the structure of the gloda database. Now, it's just a matter of writing a little JavaScript in node.js that opens an sqlite database, iterates over the folders, then the messages in each folder, and writes an mbox file for each folder. The mbox file format is trivial (just pay attention for "From"). Once you have that, you can open these mbox files in Thunderbird by just overwriting an existing empty Local Folder.

P.S. Just as a reminder: Make backups. Esp. before such migration operations, but also regularly.